# Tomcat 7 installation didn't require configure, make and make install commands

Tags: tomcat, installation

I recently installed apache tomcat 7.0.67 on rhel 6 64-bit platform. All I did was simply unzipping tar.gz file into a specified directory where I have read/write access. I was able to deploy a web app and be able to access its resources from a browser just fine.

However I stumbled upon an article about installing software on linux platform. According to it, I should have run configure, make and make install commands for any software to be installed but I don't remember doing it.

What am I missing in this picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the archive you installed had already been compiled on the same OS release and architecture.

Usually, `configure` generates the Makefiles that indicate what options you want and where you want it.  `make` generally compiles the source code into binary files specific to the architecture it's run on, which is why in most cases the `make` is necessary.  `make install` just moves the newly compiled software into the location that `configure` told it to.  If someone else already ran the necessary commands and then just compressed everything that was installed, then you wouldn't need to run anything.

In fact, that's how software packaging works.  I noticed you mentioned you installed on a RHEL platform; RPM packages are simply CPIO archives with additional metadata.  According to a .spec file, `rpmbuild` extracts the source code, runs `configure` to tell the Makefiles to install to an alternate build root directory, builds the end product with `make`, and installs it into the alternate build root directory with `make install`.  Then the .spec indicates which files are to be included in the final package and cleans itself up.

About GNU [configuration standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Configuration.html), [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html), and [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html)

About RPMs: 
[Maximum RPM](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/index.html) and [How to Create an RPM](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package)

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is a Java application thus it doesn't require any compilation "onsite" or installation tools. You just need tu unzip its archive.

Tomcat, and all java based apps, are "write-once, run everywhere". When java source code is compiled, it is converted to java *bytecode* which is **not** platform dependant.

But, as a Java app, it requires a JRE or JDK to run. And those may need compilation on your OS (usually, all OS vendors provide JRE/JDK in there repositories)

Comment: understood! Thank you for broadening my understanding on this matter. It makes sense to me.